# SQL - Selecting master IDs where there is at least one copy on every platform

Tags: sql

My apologies if this has been asked before. I wasn't sure what terms to use that broadly address this sort of issue.

I have this datatable containing master versions of videos (`master`) and copies illegally uploaded by other people (`copy`). Each `copy` is uploaded to a particular `platform`.

In this case the only possible values for `platform` are:

- facebook
- youtube
- instagram
- twitter

```
╔════════╤══════╤═══════════╗
║ master │ copy │ platform  ║
╠════════╪══════╪═══════════╣
║ 1      │ 1    │ facebook  ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 1      │ 2    │ youtube   ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 1      │ 3    │ instagram ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 1      │ 4    │ twitter   ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 1      │ 5    │ youtube   ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 1      │ 6    │ twitter   ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 2      │ 1    │ facebook  ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 2      │ 2    │ instagram ║
╟────────┼──────┼───────────╢
║ 2      │ 3    │ twitter   ║
╚════════╧══════╧═══════════╝
```

What query would I write to pull only the `master` that has at least one `copy` on each possible `platform`?

In this case, the only `master` that should be returned is 1 because it has at least one `copy` on each of the 4 possible platforms. 2 should not be returned because it does not have a `copy` on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select master
from mytable
group by master
having count(distinct plaform) = 4
```

Since you mentioned that there are only 4 possible `platform`s, it is enough to just ensure that the count of distinct `platform` values per `master` is 4.